# Snowflake - SQL Query One-to-Many Relationship

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, left-join, one-to-many

I am trying to join data from two tables. One table contains data on order items that were entered, and the other contains data on when each of those items were billed. When I left join the billing table on the order table, the order amount is duplicating when one item was billed across multiple dates.

Below is the query that I am using (this is filtered on one order to demonstrate the issue that I am having).

```
SELECT DISTINCT

O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_CREATE_DATE,
O.SALES_ORDER_ID,
LTRIM(O.MATERIAL_ID,'0') MATERIAL,
O.GSAR ORDERED_SALES,
O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_QUANTITY,
B.BILLING_DOC_DATE,
B.GSAR BILLED_SALES

FROM SALES_ORDERS O

LEFT JOIN BILLING B ON O.SALES_ORDER_ID = B.SALES_DOC_ID AND O.MATERIAL_ID = B.MATERIAL_ID AND O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_ID = B.SALES_DOC_ITEM_ID

AND O.SALES_ORDER_ID = '0306183779'
```

For this order, there are individual materials that were billed across multiple days. For example, 84 of material 503921 were ordered. The total SALES_ORDER_ITEM_QUANTITY should be 84 and the total ORDERED_SALES should be 5330.64. However, since there are multiple lines for the billing dates for material 503921, the ordered amount is being duplicated for as many billing dates as there are. The same problem is occurring for material 503995. Below is the output I am receiving.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KJsZ.png)

Below is the desired result. The BILLED_SALES should add add up to the ordered sales for each MATERIAL.

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbEHL.png)

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sample, reproducible data would be helpful, including details why you need to join on so many columns.

Comment: `ORDERED_SALES` is coming from the `SALES_ORDERS` table, which is why it is appearing as duplicated data.  What it looks like you want is to calculate a running total based on your BILLING table.  You'll want to use something like:
`SUM() OVER (PARTITIONED BY O.SALES_ORDER_ID ORDER BY B.BILLING_DOC_DATE)`

Comment: @Isolated I need to join on multiple columns because the same material can be on many orders and joining on all of the columns ensures that the join is occurring on the correct order and material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_CREATE_DATE,
O.SALES_ORDER_ID,
LTRIM(O.MATERIAL_ID,'0') MATERIAL,

case row_number() over(partition by O.SALES_ORDER_ID, O.MATERIAL_ID order by O.SALES_ORDER_ID, O.MATERIAL_ID)
   when 1 then O.GSAR
   else null
end ORDERED_SALES,
case row_number() over(partition by O.SALES_ORDER_ID, O.MATERIAL_ID order by O.SALES_ORDER_ID, O.MATERIAL_ID)
   when 1 then O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_QUANTITY
   else null
end SALES_ORDER_ITEM_QUANTITY,

B.BILLING_DOC_DATE,
B.GSAR BILLED_SALES

FROM SALES_ORDERS O

LEFT JOIN BILLING B ON O.SALES_ORDER_ID = B.SALES_DOC_ID AND O.MATERIAL_ID = B.MATERIAL_ID AND O.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_ID = B.SALES_DOC_ITEM_ID

AND O.SALES_ORDER_ID = '0306183779'

order by O.SALES_ORDER_ID, O.MATERIAL_ID
```

Comment: Mark it as the answer you were looking for.